# Call another lwc component 2 and pass recordId parameter from button click on a lwc component1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Hi I have to navigate to one lwc component from another lwc component by button click. Also have to pass recordId param to the 2nd component. I am doing below code but its not working.

```
@api recordId;

handleclick(){
callApex({json:reqString})
        .then(result =>{
            this.recordId=result;
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log('apex call error');
        })
    }  

 navigateToLightningComponent() {
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__component',
        attributes: {
            componentName: 'Component2',
        },
        "state": {
               recordId: {recordId} ,
       }

     });
 }
}
```

I am also not sure how can I pass the recordId here . Can anyone pls help me with this.

Comment: can you try to use `recordId: this.recordId`?

Comment: instead of 

    "state": {
                   recordId: {recordId} ,
           }

use 
   
    "state": {
           recordId: this.recordId ,
     }

Comment: is it ok to call navigateToLightningComponent() inside handleclick() because i am getting syntax errors. or navigateToLightningComponent need to be define outside?

Comment: Yes you can call it inside handleclick().  What kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Did you extends NavigationMixin like this ?

export default class MyCustomElement extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)